# Framework not found FacebookSDK Mountain Lion running XC 4.4.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

Why is this not working? I first installed `FacebookSDK-3.0.8.pkg` from the link:
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/

After installing, I notice the folder is created in `~/Documents/FacebookSDK/...`

I open example projects in both XC 4.4.1 and XC 4.5 B4, and get the linker error:

```
ld: framework not found FacebookSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm running Mountain Lion and have been able to compile older facebook SDKs in the past (though not in Mountain Lion).

I then installed the FacebookSDK-3.0.0.pkg package and have the same results.

**Edit**
Here is the full linker output:

```
Ld /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloFacebookSample-amabhzuzewakecehidtetsnstpuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloFacebookSample.app/HelloFacebookSample normal i386
    cd /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/Samples/HelloFacebookSample
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloFacebookSample-amabhzuzewakecehidtetsnstpuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloFacebookSample-amabhzuzewakecehidtetsnstpuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloFacebookSample-amabhzuzewakecehidtetsnstpuu/Build/Intermediates/HelloFacebookSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloFacebookSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelloFacebookSample.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -weak_framework Accounts -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -framework CoreLocation -o /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloFacebookSample-amabhzuzewakecehidtetsnstpuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloFacebookSample.app/HelloFacebookSample
```

**Fix!**
I fixed my problem.  I had installed both the `3.0.8 SDK and then the 3.0.0 SDK`, trying to get things working.  I finally decided to clean the slate and wiped my `Documents/FacebookSDK` folder and `reinstall just the 3.0.0 version`.  After wiping/reinstalling, things started working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my problem.  I had installed both the 3.0.8 SDK and then the 3.0.0 SDK, trying to get things working.  I finally decided to clean the slate and wiped my Documents/FacebookSDK folder and reinstall just the 3.0.0 version.  After wiping/reinstalling, things started working!

Comment: Thanks!  Was searching and searching for a solution.  Easy.